# How can I set a MemorySteam to the current object?

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am coding a C# application, and have a question about how to set a `MemoryStream` to the current object.

I am wanting to have a function call, for an object, that copies the object's data without returning the object, and have chosen to use serialization for this.

Here is my function inside the object that I want to copy:

```
public void CopyTest()
{
    MemoryStream stream = SerializeService.SerializeToStream(this);
    this = SerializeService.DeserializeFromStream(stream);
}
```

Here is my `SerializeToStream` function:

```
public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
    return stream;
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

> Cannot assign to '`<this>`' because it is read-only

Comment: `CopyTest` should return an `object`. You cannot assign 'this' as it gets the current instance only. `return SerializeService.DeserializeFromStream(stream);`

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve? You certainly can't reassign `this` for classes - but we don't have the context for why you're trying to do that to start with.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reassign `this`, it's the current instance. You can make your method return a copy. And you can do anything you want with that copy.
I think it needs to look more like:

```
public bool CopyTest()
{
   return this == Copy();
}

public object Copy() 
{
   return SerializeService.DeserializeFromStream(SerializeService.SerializeToStream(this));
}
```

Comment: To return the type of the object, rather than 'object', how can this be achieved other than using generics?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.